# NSTimer not calling

Tags: iphone, nstimer

I have a lot of search about this and found many solution but no one works in my case.

i am using a NSTimer and activate it from a button click here its work fine . Now i invalidate timer on second button click and start it again on third button click but on third button click my timer not works. Can anyone tell me what is the wrong with me.

Code which i am using.

button1 click :

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self      selector:@selector(updateCountdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

button2 click :

```
    if (timer != nil && [timer isValid])
    {
     [timer invalidate];
     timer=nil;
    }
```

button3 click :

```
 timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self      selector:@selector(updateCountdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

now on click on button3 timer not working.

Comment: And you have confirmed via debug logging or by using the debugger that the code for "button3 click" is actually executed?

Comment: yes its executed. checked it through debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by looking at your code . It must work . do couple of trials:

1. Check the your 3 rd button click event is being called or not .
2. Check if you are doing `timer=nil , [timer invalidate];` somewhere else .

Comment: i got solution. i invalidate timer from somewhere else. Thanks for reply.